# Removing x-axis labels from svg image in Latex

Tags: image, svg, latex

I am trying to remove x-axis labels from the current image which I have as a SVG file in Latex.
The image currently looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlKlV.png)

The code to import the SVG image in latex is:

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\def\svgwidth{0.9\columnwidth}
\includesvg{experiments/examplePicture.svg}
\caption{Picture example}
\label{labelforimage}
\end{figure}

Comment: Are you creating the svg graphic yourself or are using an external source? 
In case you are creating it yourself, I would recommend to optimize the graphic to your specific needs... e.g. enlarge the image, modify x-axis labeling, add a legend

Comment: You could edit the svg with inkscape to remove the labels

Comment: Im using the svg from an external source. Specifically, from the tensorboard dashboard to export graphs.

Comment: Got it. Edited it with Inkscape. Thank you!